# If an affine subspace doesn't intersect an affine hyperplane $H$, is it parallel to a subspace of $H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an affine subspace of $V$, say $A = x + U$ for some vector $x$ and some subspace $U$, and suppose $B$ is an affine hyperplane of $V$, say $B = y + H$ for some vector $y$ and some hyperplane $H$. Suppose $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Does this mean that $A = z + H'$ for some vector $z$ (where $z - y \notin H$) and some subspace $H'$ of $H$?

What about the converse, is it also true? That is, if I have an affine subspace $z + H'$ for some vector $z$ with $z - y \notin H$ and some subspace $H'$ of $H$, does this mean that $z+H'$ is disjoint from $B$?

It seems to be true at least when I try to picture it in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $U\not\subseteq H$.  Then as $H$ is a hyperplane, we know that $U$ and $H$ span $V$, so in particular $y-x$ lies in their span, so $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.

Thus if $A\cap B= \emptyset$, then $U\subseteq H$, so $A=z+H'$ where $z=x$ and $H'=U$ is a subspace of $H$. Finally note $z-y\notin H$ as then $x$ would be in $A\cap B$.

The converse is also true: if $z-y\notin H$, then you cannot have $y+u=z+v$, with $u,v$ both in $H$.